# My US immigrant visa was issued in India. Can I travel to the US from a different country?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, dubai

I recently interviewed for and was issued an immigrant visa to the US for me and my family. Currently we are residing in Dubai.

Can we travel to the US from Dubai even though our visa was issued by the US Embassy in India?

Answer (score 0):

For virtually all visa categories, it does not matter where you're flying from, and this goes for most of the world, not just the US.

So yes, you can fly from Dubai.